Contextual Fear Conditioning
I've been studying memory and I've come along an interesting experiment, where a rat is placed in an environment (context) and shocked, leading to fear conditioning with the conditioned stimulus being the context and the unconditioned stimulus being the shock.
After that, the "cell assembly" formed representing the memory of the environment is stimulated, and the rat freezes as a learned response to the environment.
I'm interested in the mechanism by which activating the context cell assembly causes freezing, and I have 3 ideas as to how that may occur:

The context memory activates the amygdala directly and thus activation of the context memory activates the amygdala
There are 2 memory representations: one for the context in the hippocampus and one for the shock memory in the amygdala, and both are linked together, so activating the context memory activates the shock memory
Both the context and shock are encoded in one cell assembly, and activation of that cell assembly leads to activation of the amygdala

What are your thoughts? Regardless of my ideas, is there a specific known mechanism for this process, or is it still uncertain?
Any insights or clarifications are highly anppreciated! And of course feel free to correct any mistakes I may have made here.
Thanks in advance!

I'm sorry if I may have confused you with using engram! And yes I agree the presence of a shock memory is to be expected. What I find interesting is the proposed interaction of both the shock and context memories. To be honest I was thinking about this question but I recently stumbled across the 2 memories idea so I was pretty excited but uncertain, and so I felt like the input of someone with more knowledge than me in the field would help.

And regarding "engram", do you think there is another better term to use? Perhaps cell assembly, ensemble, or just a memory?

I'm not fully sure I understood but I think the mechanism you're looking for could be related to pattern separation in the hippocampal neurons? Maybe formulating the question in a more specific way would help.

Ok, I'll try to rephrase it. Thanks for your feedback!
